# Frontend not updating when using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this blog application where I have to sort the blogs depending on the number of likes it has. This works fine when I first log in the app to see the blogs and also whenever I refresh the page. More specifically, when I first log into the app and when I refresh the page everything is/gets sorted. Is there anyway to update/sort the blog list on the fronted without refreshing the page?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Blog from './components/Blog'
import Login from './components/Login'
import CreateBlog from './components/CreateBlog'
import blogService from './services/blogs'
import loginService from './services/login'
import './app.css';

const App = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]) // Unsorted array
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('')
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState('')
  const [sortedArray, setSortedArray] = useState(null) //This sorts the original blog array

  const [visibility, setVisibility] = useState(false)


  useEffect( () => {
    if(user != null){
      setBlogs(user.blog)
      setSortedArray(user.blog.sort((a,b) => parseInt(b.likes) - parseInt(a.likes)))
    }
    console.log("blogs is", blogs)
  }, [user,sortedArray])

  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedInUser = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedBlogUser')
    console.log("loggedInUser is", loggedInUser)
    if(loggedInUser){
      const user = JSON.parse(loggedInUser)
      blogService.setToken(user.token)
      console.log("user is", user)
      setUser(user)
    }
    else{
      console.log("Error here,", JSON.parse(loggedInUser))
    }
  },[])


  const handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log("Logging in,", username, password)
    try {
      const user = await loginService({username, password})
      setBlogs(user.blog)
      setSortedArray(user.blog.sort((a,b) => parseInt(b.likes) - parseInt(a.likes)))
      blogService.setToken(user.token)
      window.localStorage.setItem('loggedBlogUser', JSON.stringify(user))
      setUser(user)
      setUsername('')
      setPassword('')
    }
    catch(error){
      setErrorMsg('Wrong username or password')
      setTimeout(() => {
        setErrorMsg('')
      },3000)
    }
  }

  const handleLogout = () => {
    window.localStorage.removeItem('loggedBlogUser')
    setUser(null)
    setBlogs([])
    setSortedArray([])

  }

  const addNewBlog = async (blogObject) => {
    try {
      const result = await blogService.createBlog(blogObject)
      const result2 = await blogService.getUserBlogs(result.blog.slice(-1)[0])
      user.blog = user.blog.concat(result2)
      window.localStorage.setItem('loggedBlogUser', JSON.stringify(user))
      setBlogs(user.blog)
      setSortedArray(user.blog.sort((a,b) => parseInt(b.likes) - parseInt(a.likes)))
      console.log("USER USER USER IS", user)
      setVisibility(false)
      setMsg(`a new blog ${blogObject.title} by ${user.name} added`)
      setTimeout(() => {
        setMsg('')
      },3000)
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log("error adding new blog", error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>blogs</h2>
      {msg !== '' && <h1 className='successMsg-container'>{msg}</h1>}
      {errorMsg !== '' && <h1 className='errorMsg-container'>{errorMsg}</h1>}
      {user == null && 
      <Login
        handleLogin={handleLogin}
        setUsername={setUsername}
        setPassword={setPassword}
        username={username}
        password={password}>
      </Login>
      }
      {user != null && <div className="notes">
        <p>{user.name} logged in <button onClick={handleLogout}>logout</button></p>
      </div>}
      {user != null && 
      <CreateBlog
        addNewBlog={addNewBlog}
        visibility={visibility} 
        setVisibility={setVisibility}>
      </CreateBlog>
      }
      {sortedArray !== null && sortedArray.map(blog =>
        <Blog key={blog.id} blog={blog} setBlogs={setBlogs} setSortedArray={setSortedArray} user={user} />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Blog code

```
import blogService from "../services/blogs"

const Blog = ({blog,user,setBlogs,setSortedArray}) => {
  const [view, setView] = useState(false)
  const [likeCount, setLikeCount] = useState(0)
  

  const hideWhenVisible = {display: view ? 'none' : ''}
  const showWhenVisible = {display: view ? '': 'none'}

  const handleLikeClick = async (blog) => {
    const id = blog.id
    const actualBlog = await blogService.getUserBlogs(id)

    try {
      const updatedBlog = {
        user: [blog.user[0]],
        likes: actualBlog.likes + 1,
        author: blog.author,
        id: actualBlog.id,
        title: blog.title,
        url: blog.url
      }
      setLikeCount(updatedBlog.likes)

      var elementPos = user.blog.map(ranBlog => {return ranBlog.id}).indexOf(blog.id)
      user.blog[elementPos] = updatedBlog
      window.localStorage.setItem('loggedBlogUser', JSON.stringify(user))

      const result = await blogService.updateBlog(updatedBlog,id)

    }
    catch(error){
      console.log("error liking blog")
    }
  }

  return ( 
    <div className="blog-container">
        {blog.title}  
        <button onClick={() => setView(true)} style={hideWhenVisible}>view</button>
        <button onClick={() => setView(false)} style={showWhenVisible}>hide</button>
          {view && <div className="expanded-view-container">
            <li className="extra-blog-info">
              <ul>{blog.url}</ul>
            {likeCount === 0 && <ul>likes: {blog.likes} <button onClick={() => handleLikeClick(blog)}>like</button></ul>}
            {likeCount !== 0 && <ul>likes: {likeCount} <button onClick={() => handleLikeClick(blog)}>like</button></ul>}
              <ul>{blog.author}</ul>
              <ul>{blog.id}</ul>
            </li>
          </div>}
    </div> 
   );
}
 
export default Blog;
```

Comment: What is your condition for re-sorting blogs? I haven't seen you've mentioned it in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So every time a blog gets liked, it gets a new sorted array but this sorted array does not automatically change the order of the blogs on the frontend. It only does so when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code of `Blog` component, I have seen that you haven't called `setBlogs` and `setSortedArray` which update blog states from `App`.

I'd propose you should have another callback function called `afterLikeClicked` in `Blog` to update `blogs` state which will make UI re-rendered.

```
import blogService from "../services/blogs"

const Blog = ({blog, user, afterLikeClicked}) => {
  const [view, setView] = useState(false)
  const [likeCount, setLikeCount] = useState(0)
  

  const hideWhenVisible = {display: view ? 'none' : ''}
  const showWhenVisible = {display: view ? '': 'none'}

  const handleLikeClick = async (blog) => {
    const id = blog.id
    const actualBlog = await blogService.getUserBlogs(id)

    try {
      const updatedBlog = {
        user: [blog.user[0]],
        likes: actualBlog.likes + 1,
        author: blog.author,
        id: actualBlog.id,
        title: blog.title,
        url: blog.url
      }
      setLikeCount(updatedBlog.likes)
      
      //The change is here
      afterLikeClicked(updatedBlog)

      var elementPos = user.blog.map(ranBlog => {return ranBlog.id}).indexOf(blog.id)
      user.blog[elementPos] = updatedBlog
      window.localStorage.setItem('loggedBlogUser', JSON.stringify(user))

      const result = await blogService.updateBlog(updatedBlog,id)

    }
    catch(error){
      console.log("error liking blog")
    }
  }

  return ( 
    <div className="blog-container">
        {blog.title}  
        <button onClick={() => setView(true)} style={hideWhenVisible}>view</button>
        <button onClick={() => setView(false)} style={showWhenVisible}>hide</button>
          {view && <div className="expanded-view-container">
            <li className="extra-blog-info">
              <ul>{blog.url}</ul>
            {likeCount === 0 && <ul>likes: {blog.likes} <button onClick={() => handleLikeClick(blog)}>like</button></ul>}
            {likeCount !== 0 && <ul>likes: {likeCount} <button onClick={() => handleLikeClick(blog)}>like</button></ul>}
              <ul>{blog.author}</ul>
              <ul>{blog.id}</ul>
            </li>
          </div>}
    </div> 
   );
}
 
export default Blog;
```

And then update `App` accordingly

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Blog from './components/Blog'
import Login from './components/Login'
import CreateBlog from './components/CreateBlog'
import blogService from './services/blogs'
import loginService from './services/login'
import './app.css';

const App = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]) // Unsorted array
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('')
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState('')
  const [sortedArray, setSortedArray] = useState(null) //This sorts the original blog array

  const [visibility, setVisibility] = useState(false)


  useEffect( () => {
    if(user != null){
      setBlogs(user.blog)
      setSortedArray(user.blog.sort((a,b) => parseInt(b.likes) - parseInt(a.likes)))
    }
    console.log("blogs is", blogs)
  }, [user,sortedArray])

  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedInUser = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedBlogUser')
    console.log("loggedInUser is", loggedInUser)
    if(loggedInUser){
      const user = JSON.parse(loggedInUser)
      blogService.setToken(user.token)
      console.log("user is", user)
      setUser(user)
    }
    else{
      console.log("Error here,", JSON.parse(loggedInUser))
    }
  },[])


  const handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log("Logging in,", username, password)
    try {
      const user = await loginService({username, password})
      setBlogs(user.blog)
      setSortedArray(user.blog.sort((a,b) => parseInt(b.likes) - parseInt(a.likes)))
      blogService.setToken(user.token)
      window.localStorage.setItem('loggedBlogUser', JSON.stringify(user))
      setUser(user)
      setUsername('')
      setPassword('')
    }
    catch(error){
      setErrorMsg('Wrong username or password')
      setTimeout(() => {
        setErrorMsg('')
      },3000)
    }
  }

  const handleLogout = () => {
    window.localStorage.removeItem('loggedBlogUser')
    setUser(null)
    setBlogs([])
    setSortedArray([])
  }

  const addNewBlog = async (blogObject) => {
    try {
      const result = await blogService.createBlog(blogObject)
      const result2 = await blogService.getUserBlogs(result.blog.slice(-1)[0])
      user.blog = user.blog.concat(result2)
      window.localStorage.setItem('loggedBlogUser', JSON.stringify(user))
      setBlogs(user.blog)
      setSortedArray(user.blog.sort((a,b) => parseInt(b.likes) - parseInt(a.likes)))
      console.log("USER USER USER IS", user)
      setVisibility(false)
      setMsg(`a new blog ${blogObject.title} by ${user.name} added`)
      setTimeout(() => {
        setMsg('')
      },3000)
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log("error adding new blog", error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>blogs</h2>
      {msg !== '' && <h1 className='successMsg-container'>{msg}</h1>}
      {errorMsg !== '' && <h1 className='errorMsg-container'>{errorMsg}</h1>}
      {user == null && 
      <Login
        handleLogin={handleLogin}
        setUsername={setUsername}
        setPassword={setPassword}
        username={username}
        password={password}>
      </Login>
      }
      {user != null && <div className="notes">
        <p>{user.name} logged in <button onClick={handleLogout}>logout</button></p>
      </div>}
      {user != null && 
      <CreateBlog
        addNewBlog={addNewBlog}
        visibility={visibility} 
        setVisibility={setVisibility}>
      </CreateBlog>
      }
      {sortedArray !== null && sortedArray.map(blog =>
        <Blog key={blog.id} blog={blog} afterLikeClicked={(updatedBlog) => {
            const updatedBlogs = blogs.map((blog) => blog.id === updatedBlog.id ? updatedBlog : blog)
            //update original blogs
            setBlogs(updatedBlogs)
            //update sorted blogs
            setSortedArray(updatedBlogs.sort((a,b) => parseInt(b.likes) - parseInt(a.likes)))
        }} user={user} />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```